# What is the random string I am seeing when I use get_query_var?

Tags: wp-query, advanced-custom-fields, meta-query

I am setting up an advanced search page with ACF fields with a custom post type in wordpress.

In my example I am sending 'Students' in my url parameters as ?licenseType=Students

[image: Search Example]

*EDIT adding PHP code:

```
<select id="licenseType" name="licenseType">
<option value="">All License Types</option>
            <?php $field = get_field_object('software_license_type');               
                    if( $field )
                    {
                        foreach( $field['choices'] as $key => $value )
                        {
                            echo '<option value="'.$key.'" '.((isset($_GET['licenseType']) && $_GET['licenseType'] == $value)?' selected':'').' >'.$value.'</option>';
                        }
                    }
            ?></select>
```

I have registered my query_vars

```
 add_filter( 'query_vars', 'software_register_query_vars' );
 function software_register_query_vars( $vars ) {
    $vars[] = 'licenseType';
  return $vars;
 }
```

and set up my pre_get_posts filter

```
add_action('pre_get_posts','software_pre_get_posts');
function software_pre_get_posts( $query ) {
  if ( is_main_query() && $query->get('post_type') == 'uc_software' ) {
    $query->set('nopaging','true');  
    $query->set( 'orderby', 'title' ); 
    $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' ); 

    $meta_query = array(); 

    if( !empty( get_query_var( 'licenseType' ) ) ){
    $meta_query[] = array( 'key' => 'software_license_type', 'value' => 
    get_query_var( 'licenseType' ), 'compare' => 'LIKE' );
    }
// ...
//I will add more fields here...
// ...  
    if( count( $meta_query ) > 1 ){
      $meta_query['relation'] = 'AND';
    }

    if( count( $meta_query ) > 0 ){
      $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
    }   
  }
}
```

When I view the query that is being created I see

```
SELECT wp_125_posts.* FROM wp_125_posts INNER JOIN wp_125_postmeta ON ( 
wp_125_posts.ID = wp_125_postmeta.post_id ) WHERE 1=1 AND ( ( 
wp_125_postmeta.meta_key = 'software_license_type' AND 
wp_125_postmeta.meta_value LIKE 
 '{4d69cec85576e5c23416d1afb6df73c1a4a288f24aff1da852b18ad70b464309}Students{4d69cec85576e5c23416d1afb6df73c1a4a288f24aff1da852b18ad70b464309}' 
) ) AND wp_125_posts.post_type = 'uc_software' AND (wp_125_posts.post_status = 'publish' 
OR wp_125_posts.post_status = 'acf-disabled' OR wp_125_posts.post_status = 'private') 
GROUP BY wp_125_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_125_posts.post_title ASC
```

What is the random string that is being captured along with my query_var? Is there a way I can retrieve my query_var without it? I see the same thing when I use $_GET['licenseType'].

Comment: What’s the code for the form? Where the select field is made.

Comment: I don't think that is relevant but I will add it. My url does say ...com?/licenseType=Students&....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a symptom of having a `%` character in your meta query value. Since 4.8.3 `%` characters are being escaped (actually replaced by a semi random string) and should be unescaped before executing the sql query.

You should check with the plugin author what would be the best way to handle it, but in your specific case I would say that slight redesign to your code would be a better solution than any unescaping code. `LIKE` is an expensive operation better be avoided and based on your UI you can just make a strict compare of values instead.

Comment: I am the plugin author :D I changed to = compare and it works! Thank you!

Comment: lol meant ACF as it is a common problem with it and I thought they might have some special solution

Comment: I remember why I used LIKE, now. When I add multiple meta_query arrays the search will work with LIKE but not =

Comment: are you storing it in serialized form?. The additional danger with a `Like` is that it will match things that it should not.

Comment: Yes, it IS stored in serialized form. Thanks again!!

Comment: in that case, is it possible just not to store it like that? I am not familiar with ACF, but if you use core meta APIs you can store each meta in its own row with the same key. I assume there should be a way doing that with ACF as well